# Не отображается полоска под фото css

Tags: css, img

```css
.work__icon {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.work__icon:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 240px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: chartreuse;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
}
```

С текстом линия появляется, а с фотографией нету

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос сформулирован в расчете на телепата, поэтому могу лишь предположить, что  вы пытаетесь показать псевдоэлемент у тега `<img>`.
Это не сработает, т.к. псевдоэлемент может быть только у элемента, у которого возможны дочерние элементы. У картинки их быть не может, так что тут облом.
Меняйте структуру HTML.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Прошу прощения за формулировку, пока сам не понимаю, как мысли излогать на языке IT